# Copy columns based on set paramaters

Tags: vba, excel

I am copying information from one workbook to another. The code I have so far works great if every column has data. It does not work when I am trying to repeatedly copy information from column A and B of worksheet(supplementary expenses) to worksheet(expenses) and column B is blank. As the next time the sub is run and Column B does have values they are placed in the next blank cell, not the cell that is correlated to column A.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub SupplementaryExpenses()

 Dim x As Workbook
 Dim y As Workbook

 Set y = Workbooks.Open("File Path")
 Set x = Workbooks.Open("File Path")


x.Sheets("b.1 Supplementary expenses").Range("a9", Range("a9").End(xlDown)).Copy
y.Sheets("Expenses").Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

x.Sheets("b.1 Supplementary expenses").Range("b9", Range("b9").End(xlDown)).Copy
y.Sheets("Expenses").Range("b1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

x.Sheets("b.1 Supplementary expenses").Range("c9", Range("c9").End(xlDown)).Copy
y.Sheets("Expenses").Range("c1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Also any time this sub is run it would be helpful if there were someway to fill column L with the flag 201601 and then change to 201602 when I bring in the next months data.

Comment: Qualify ***all*** instances of `Range()`, `Cells()`, `Columns()`, etc. You did this with the first part of your ranges (`x.Sheets("b.1 Supplementary expenses").Range("a9"...`), but not the next one ( `Range("a9").End(xlDown)`).  If you add the references to that, it'll help a lot with the code.

Comment: In the future it would be helpful to specify exactly how it's "not working", e.g. nothing happens, or something is happening you don't expect, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub SupplementaryExpenses()

 Dim x As Workbook
 Dim y As Workbook
 Dim lastrow As Long
 Dim tRow as long


 Set y = Workbooks.Open("File Path")
 Set x = Workbooks.Open("File Path")
 With x.Sheets("b.1 Supplementary expenses")

     lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     tRow = y.Sheets("Expenses").Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row
     y.Sheets("Expenses").Range("A" & trow).Resize(lastrow - 8, 3).Value = .Range(.Cells(9, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 3)).Value
     y.Sheets("Expenses").Range("D" & trow).Resize(lastrow - 8, 1).Value = .Range(.Cells(9, 8), .Cells(lastrow, 8)).Value
 End With

End Sub
```

It will take all of the three columns at once and assign the values to the new area.  It will  not  care about blanks in column B or C.

This should be faster than copy/paste as you only want the values.

Comment: So you want to copy columns A,B,C and H from the original and paste them to A,B,C and D of the target?  If so you will add a line.

Comment: The added line has the same issue I was having with original code. Column D is offset from Columns A:C.

Comment: @Don yeah I did not think it totally through.  I changed a few things so look at the whole code.

Comment: Solved. Thank you Scott, would not have been able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Get the last used row and change out your range statements similar to this:

```
    Dim LastRow
    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    x.Sheets("b.1 Supplementary expenses").Range(Cells(9, 1), Cells(LastRow, a)).Copy 'this is R1C1 format meaning row then column
```

You can use this for filling a column
If you put it after the rest of your code and ensure that you have the sheet you want column L populated with active:

```
     sDate = Format(Date, "yyyymm")    
     For i = 2 To LastRow' you may need to grab this anew if you added lines
      If Cells(i, "L") = vbNullString Then 'ensures that there isn't anything in the cell
        Cells(i, "L").value = sDate
      End If
     Next
```

Comment: Having some issues creating an InputBox in your code, here is what I have so far:
`Dim myValue As Variant
      Dim myValue1 As Variant
         myValue = InputBox("Period?")
     myValue1 = InputBox("SVC, RCV, Yale?")
 For i = 2 To lastrow - 6 lines
       If Cells(i, "B") = vbNullString Then 
        Cells(i, "B").Value = "myValue1"
      End If
     Next 
     
     For i = 2 To lastrow - 6 
      If Cells(i, "C") = vbNullString Then 
        Cells(i, "C").Value = "myValue"`

Instead of displaying the userinput my code is displaying "myvalue" or  "myvalue1"

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what your issue is but you do have "For i = 2 To lastrow - 6 lines" and that word "lines" isn't helping ... I commented that out and added a "next" to this code along with a sub/end sub and it runs for me. Where are you having an issue and what is it?

Comment: Alos, I don't see the code snippet creating lastrow in what you pasted there, I assume it is in your code before this part? Otherwise it won't do anything with your for/next loops.